# upper case to lowercase

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, cs50

I just started learning programming, and I started with C, and I am just goofing around and trying to make a function that changes a letters in a string from uppercase to all lowercase, and then return it in an array of lowercase letters...

My code doesn't work. And I'm tired of googling. can somebody please help me please?

Here is what I have up until now:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string lowercase(char inlower[]);

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Type in a word: ");
    char inlower[strlen(word)];

    printf("You typed: %s\n", word);
}

string lowercase(string word)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        inlower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        // printf("%c", inlower[i]);
    }
    return inlower[];
}
```

Comment: Obviously it doesn't work? It's not obvious to us, especially since not all of us have access to `cs50.h`. Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: you don't use `char inlower[strlen(word)];` variable at all, also you forgot to add 1 symbol for 0 terminator

Comment: you don't use `string lowercase(string word)` function at all, probably you want to actually call it

Comment: `inlower` is not declared inside of function, so you need to define it

Comment: `return inlower[];` - no need to use `[]` here, you're not defining array, you want to return variable

Comment: function `lowercase` returns string, so you need to define string variable, not char array

Comment: btw, you forward declaration of lowercase function differs from actual definition, you need to decide - do you want to accept string or char array, these types are very different

Comment: Be aware that in the infamous CS50 course they make you believe that there is actually a `string` type when there is no such thing in C.

Comment: I am sorry Chris, I just didn't think it mattered at this point. The problems with my code are just... broader than what concerns cs50.h...

Comment: Wow I am impressed at how fast you get an answe here... thanks alot, all of you <3... I tried to solve the.. all the misstakes, when I actually got a full sullution before I had time to finnish... thank you

Comment: Providing error information is useful in getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on `word` and return `word`, not `word[]`. `inlower` is local to `main` and can't be used in `lowercase`, unless you pass it along as a parameter along with `word`.

Also note that you should cast the `char` in your `char[]` (`string`) to `unsigned char` before using it with `tolower`. If `char` is signed and  the `char[]` contains negative values, calling `tolower` will cause undefined behavior.

```c
#include <cs50.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string lowercase(string word)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0, len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        word[i] = tolower((unsigned char) word[i]);
    }
    return word;
}

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Type in a word: ");

    printf("You typed: %s\n", lowercase(word));
}
```

---

If you do want to put the lowercase word in `inlower` that you've declared in `main`, you also need to make it big enough for what you have in `word`. `strlen(word)` is one `char` short since every string must be terminated with a `\0` `char`.

```c
string lowercase(string inlower, string word)
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    for (unsigned len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        inlower[i] = tolower((unsigned char) word[i]);
    }
    inlower[i] = '\0';
    return inlower;
}

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Type in a word: ");

    char inlower[strlen(word) + 1]; // correct size

    lowercase(inlower, word); // pass `inlower` in to `lowercase` too

    printf("You typed:    %s\n"
           "In lowercase: %s\n", word, inlower);
}
```

Alternative version without doing `strlen` inside `lowercase` too:

```
string lowercase(string inlower, string word)
{
    string dest = inlower;
    for(;*word; ++word, ++dest)
    {
        *dest = tolower((unsigned char) *word);
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return inlower;
}
```

Comment: yes I did and and it was really useful to me. Haven't had time to check out the alternative version yet, but I get it all much better already. Have been leaning and trying different things almost non-stop since! ")

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev The alternative version is just that, an alternative. It's probably not even better, just an alternative showing how you can use the pointers (`string` is a `char*`) and step forward and dereference them to see what they are pointing at.